# Marshall or UnMarshall case object with SprayJsonSupport

Tags: akka, spray-json

I have a case object in an actor like this:

```
 object UserActor{

  case object getResult

  def props = Props(new UserActor)
}

class UserActor extends Actor {

    def receive = {

    case getResult =>

        val reply =  sender

        reply ! "Hello world"
    }
}
```

which I want to use in a route as this:

```
 val route: Route =
          path("users") { id =>
            get {
              complete {
                userActor ? getResult
              }
              }
            }
```

However, I got the error, expected ToResponseMarshallable. So question, how do I marshall case object using SprayJsonSupport?